# Removing url scope segment with url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs, rails-routing

I'm writing an app that makes use of AngularJS, so the app is setup to route all requests to the main home page where angular takes over. All routes are then defined within an api scope which angular uses to retrieve the data. It's setup though, that if the user navigates to a page with a normal URL, then when it redirects to the home page, it maintains that URL which angular then uses to load the correct state.

What I now want to do, is be able to use URL helpers within rails to generate my URL's, but not have the generated URL's include the /api of the scope. Is there any way I can get around this?

`routes.rb` looks a bit like

```
scope "/api", shallow_path: "/api" do
    ... normal stuff here ...
end
```

And if I try using one of the helpers,

```
meeting_url(@meeting, subdomain: "test")
```

the url it generates is

```
http://test.domain.com/api/meetings/1
```

Is there a way I can have it strip the `/api`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a built-in way to do it.

But, you're in ruby, so there are plenty of ways to do what you want.

One way to go, since you're in your own app, is do monkey-patch `String`:

```
class String
  def no_api
    self.gsub(/\/api/, '')
  end
end

meeting_url(@meeting, subdomain: 'test').no_api #=> http://test.domain.com/meetings/1
```

If you find that distasteful, you can define a method on `ApplicationController` or in a helper module:

```
def no_api(url)
  url.gsub(/\/api/, '')
end
```

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I figured that'd probably be the only approach. Will just have to do that :) cheers :)